# How to find element ID based on container

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a Django project where, on the homepage, I am generating rows on the click of a button. By default, row0 exists. When the button is clicked, a 'row1' is created, and when clicked again, 'row2' is created, and so on... In each row exists the same items: a search bar, a button, and a number input. Their IDs are created based on a counter. so the button creates a div with the ID 'row1' then in that row goes 'search1' 'button1' and 'number_input1'

When the button is clicked, it takes the value input into the 'search0' element, and finds a value corresponding to that input... The problem is, I am finding the value by referencing the search bar with the id 'search0' although someone may be using row3... SO I am trying to determine how to find the search bar in the same row as the button being clicked.

Example: If I click 'button3' (the button in the third row), then how can I reference 'search3'(the search bar in row3) without using it's ID. The trick is, this cannot be a static string because the rows are created dynamically, thus all buttons share the same function.

Is there a way to check the row it's in, then pull the value in the search element in the same row...?

here is the check value function

```
function checkQty(id){

                    value = document.getElementById("search0").value;
                    button = document.getElementById(id);
                    
                    for (i=0; i < products_qty.length; i++){
                        if (products_qty[i][0] == value){
                            button.innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(products_qty[i][1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The button passes its own id into the function with the 'id' variable, but I am searching by 'search0' no matter which button is pressed

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using a substring to get the row number of the button, then replacing "search0" with the correct row number instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @willi123yao, I did some research into substrings and came up with the following solution

```
function checkQty(id){
                    rowNum = id.substring(id.length - 1, id.length);

                    value = document.getElementById("search"+rowNum).value;
                    button = document.getElementById(id);
                    
                    for (i=0; i < products_qty.length; i++){
                        if (products_qty[i][0] == value){
                            button.innerHTML =  JSON.stringify(products_qty[i][1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Essentially I am taking the last character of the ID for the button being passed through and then inserting it on the search to make sure the search and button are in the same row. I tested this and it works to perfection